# Get running worker by parameters in Celery

Tags: python, django, postgresql, redis, celery

I am trying to implement time-consuming calculations with Celery (v 3.1.25). I need to get already running worker by the parameter that passed when the task was started.

Client passes company_id to the server and Celery starts the worker with given parameter. There could be many clients that pass the same company_id, so I have to check that the process is not already running. If it is running the task should not be scheduled, because the result of running the same process always the same and we have to tell him that task is already running.

```
@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def calculate(self, company_id):
    obj_list = get_objects(company_id)

    for i, obj in enumerate(obj_list):
        self.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': i, 'total': len(obj_list)})

        result = calc(
            registry=registry_key,
            company_id=company_id,
        )

    return result
```

I'm thinking about storing the current status in `Postgres` database, where the model would be `work_id, status (PROGRESS/SUCCESS), start_time, finish_time`. In this case the question is how to handle that status of the work has changed? And is it correct to store such information in database?
Are there any other variants of solving this problem?

I was looking at [celery-once](https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once), but did not find there the method that could tell me that this process is running (I want to tell that to user).

Maybe I could do something with Redis?